# Find multiple words and paste them in different sheets

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I am currently using the code below to find multiple values and then to copy/paste into another sheet. The purpose of this code is to retrieve a list of genes (small words) from huge data set.

This code is for one gene list (a list of small keywords) only, which is present in Sheet 3 Column A (beginning with A2). All the data retrieved from the huge data set (present in Sheet 1) is copied to Sheet 2.

Now I have 6 gene lists (6 lists of small keywords). I have to make 6 separate sheets for all these gene lists. Kindly tell me the code for this problem.

```
Sub OrderFinder()
    Dim srchLen, gName, nxtRw As Integer
    Dim g As Range

    'Clear Sheet 2 and Copy Column Headings
    Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(1)

    'Determine length of Search Column from Sheet3
    srchLen = Sheets(3).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through list in Sheet3, Column A. As each value is
    'found in Sheet1, Column B, copy it too the next row in Sheet2
    With Sheets(1).Columns("B")
        For gName = 2 To srchLen
            Set g = .Find(Sheets(3).Range("A" & gName), lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not g Is Nothing Then
                nxtRw = Sheets(2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                g.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A" & nxtRw)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```